# Return type of function provided by the return type of a callback provided as an argument

Tags: typescript

In the bottom example `shouldBeString` comes up as a type `any`, when I am expecting a `string`

```
function doThing<T, T2>(fn: (p: T) => T2) {
    return fn({} as any)
}

interface Ok {
    thing: string
}

const shouldBeString = doThing<Ok>(ctx =>ctx.thing)
```

Why isn't the return type correct?

[TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgFQBYzAcwDxoA0iaATAHwAUwYAXIpQA71oCUiAvOSaewN4AoRMMQAnAKZQQopDUp8AvogCGAZxVgAnqwEKBA7FHGjgyiOMQB5ANaJBIxFCy56qqKOw5d+iAjeI4Ww4UdGd8GypoAA9OcmiAOidPdiA)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying only some of the template type arguments is not currently allowed by TypeScript. You can follow the discussion on allowing only a subset of generic type parameters on GitHub:

[Allow specifying only a subset of generic type parameters explicitly instead of all vs none](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597)

The immediate solution is to set both template arguments

```
const actualString = doThing<Ok, string>(ctx => ctx.thing)
```

or, instead, properly type the callback and let the compiler infer both `T` and `T2`

```
const actualString = doThing((ctx: Ok) => ctx.thing)
```

**Why the return type `any`**

Since your are not providing the correct type parameters, the return type is then inferred by the TypeScript compiler and, in your example, `ctx` is of type `any` so `ctx.thing` is also of type `any` which in turn marks `T2` as `any`.